# FlashDevelop iOS Export - Security error

Tags: iphone, ios, actionscript-3

when trying to load a local swf in my actionscript 3 project for iOS I get the following
error in the debugger:

```
[Fault] exception, information=SecurityError: Error #3207: Application-sandbox content cannot access this feature.
```

Im stuck, any advice?

Security.allowDomain("*");

gives me the same results.

Mirza

Answer (score 0):

In the loader object, have you set a LoaderContext object on the load() function?

Comment: yes, this is what I did: // entry point
   Security.allowDomain("*");
   
   var mLoader:Loader = new Loader();
   var mRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("DSDShell.swf");
   var _lc:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain, null);
   mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);

   mLoader.load(mRequest, _lc);

Comment: in a debugger a local test did fine with this code:

import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var l:Loader = new Loader();

l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

l.load(new URLRequest("test_swf.swf"));


function onComplete(e:Event):void
{
 addChild(l.content);
}

Comment: not on my side...really strange, Im using flashdevelop with the latest air sdk, Im getting the same security error

Comment: When I run the SWF outside debugger, it workes fine ad loads the other swf...but not in the adl test debugger, thats strange

Comment: when I package it as ipa, do I need to embed the local swf on some place?

Comment: It's a strange thing to say, but I prefer to do packaging with Flash Professional, because of more clear and friendly interface that allows me to include folders and files in the package.
I can't help much with info about Flash Develop, because I use a Mac, but the must be a project properties panel and a command line for compiler options. Google the compiler code syntax to add a file/folder to a package and I'm sure you'll do just fine.

And I don't think you need Security.allowDomain() for local SWF, I think it's for external files from other servers.

Comment: Then a few tips for you (all done in the properties panel):

1) In the Script settings, you'll have a window with 3 tabs: Source path, Library path, Config constants. Modify the source path from "." to "/src/", because by default in FD your folder is "src" (and that's good). In the library path include your SWC if you use any. You can also make the compiler constants if you use any (conditional compilation)

2) In the Target settings you'll have 4 panels: General, Deployment, Icons and Languages.

Comment: Target settings are easy, just include all the packages with the GUI and have an easy time packaging your AIR app for mobile. Hope it helps!